# Does changing the master username on an RDS PostgreSQL DB cause a reboot?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've read the docs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/) on how to "Reset the Master User Password" for an AWS RDS DB.

When done, you have to click **Modify DB Instance** which says:

> The Status field for your RDS DB instance on the RDS dashboard changes to **resetting-master-credentials**. When the modification is complete, the Status column changes to **Available**.

Does anyone know if this causes the DB to reboot? I want to change the password with zero downtime to the DB. The AWS docs are unclear about this.

Answer (score 4):

This does not cause a reboot

The [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/) states the following

> The password change is asynchronous, and applies as soon as possible. This change ignores the Apply Immediately setting.

This means it will apply in the background, not during a maintenance period or reboot.

Comment: It's also explicitly mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html#USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.Settings) in "Downtime notes" column